# WPF Trigger command

Tags: wpf, behavior

I know in Silverlight there is a concept  of behaviours.

In WPF we have Triggers,

What I am trying to achieve is that when a user has his mouse over a button, I want a command to be fired.

I have a RepeatButton that has its Command Property set, but I want that command (or preferable another command to fire) when the mouse is over that button.Is this possible in WPF.

The Button is in a Control Template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048517/wpf-calling-commands-via-events)