# Detecting a panel load on Prism

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

I can't seem to find a way to detect when a panel finishes loading.  I'm adding a couple features to an already existing WPF/Prism project.  I need to get called back when the page finishes rendering.  I tried this:

In the UserControl at the top of the XAML that I need to get called back on when the page loads:

```
<UserControl x:....

xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
...>

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoSomething}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Then in the code behind file:

```
public void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("received callback");
}
```

It currently does not work and I was not sure if this is the right path or not since I'm new to WPF, prism, and .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I see you already know the answer... anyway...
What you did wrong you had been binding event to command in your XAML and you didn't have command :) Basicly you messed up standard "code-behind approach" with let's say "MVVM approach"/binding.

So when you touched the code-behind and created your `DoSomethingEventHandler` there you could simply

```xml
    <UserControl .. Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"> 
    .. 
    </UserControl>
```

with your CodeBehind:

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
```

It would be fine... but it's not MVVM :]

Well and to your new approach (no code-behind/let's say MVVM)...

If you use Prism v4.1 you can look [here](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/5495) this feature most people miss in Prism :) but there is solution mentioned :)

Well as you know you need `ICommand` you are binding to... It does not have to be `DelegateCommand` you can use what you want... (I prefer and use `RelayCommand`)

Well but what we learned from aforementioned link?

1. Sometimes... not this time... `ICommand` can change Controls enabled state and it's not updated when you don't use `Prism's Interactivity` and you simply use `Blend SDK's Interactivity`... You don't need it this time... I admit... but maybe some day :)
2. And you don't need those silly parameters in handler since you don't get them anyway :D(When you need those Args You can use MVVM Light for example.)

So the best you can do is this:

```xml
<UserControl
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity"
...    
>
...
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and your ViewModel for example:

```
    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(this.MyCommandExecute);
        }
    }

    private void MyCommandExecute()
    {
        // DO Something...
    }
```

Sorry that I unswered already answered question, but I thought I might add some interesting info :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I just figured it out.  Found this post: [Binding the Loaded event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887867/binding-the-loaded-event)

I needed to create a new DelegateCommand

```
public DelegateCommand DoSomething {get; set; }
```

Then bind it to a callback:

```
DoSomething = new DelegateCommand(DoSomethingCommandHandler);
```

And then in my

```
private void DoSomethingCommandHandler
{
    // callback received
}
```

Seems to work.  Let me know if there is something better.  Like I said, I'm totally noob.