# Handling keyboard press in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, command

I am only beginning to learn MVVM and its use in WPF.

I am using it to build a very simple Calculator application (like the Windows built in calculator).

One thing i've noticed, is that binding my view (XAML) to commands does not let me configure WHEN these actual commands are fired.

For example, a Button control fires the command bound to it when it is clicked.

I would like to achieve the same effect when the numpad buttons are presed ('1' will fire the Command of the "1" Button control, and so on).

I could not find 1 way to do this, all sites seem to show multiple other options which don't seem valid in this case.

Should this be set up in the Control's (Button) level or on the entire window? How can i do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048517/wpf-calling-commands-via-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set input bindings of your main window.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="D1" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="NumPad1" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```