# How to bind a Command to SelectedItemChanged event of a TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview, command, selecteditemchanged

There is a Treeview Control.

```
 <TreeView Name="ProductsHierarchy" FontFamily="Arial"  
                          Background="White" Margin="2" 
                          FontSize="12" SelectedItemChanged ="ProductsHierarchy_SelectedItemChanged">
```

Is there a way to bind a command for SelectedItemChanged event of the treeview, avoiding the code behind event handler?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048517/wpf-calling-commands-via-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [MVVM Toolkit's EventToCommand](http://adammills.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/eventtocommand-action-mvvm-glue/).

"Built-in" (from Blend) approach is to use Interactivity

```
<TreeView Name="ProductsHierarchy" FontFamily="Arial"  
                          Background="White" Margin="2" 
                          FontSize="12" SelectedItemChanged ="ProductsHierarchy_SelectedItemChanged">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="argument"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeView>
```

You must include namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

The disadvantage here is that you have no access to `EventArgs`. Here's the [solution](http://www.pzielinski.com/?p=943) (it's in Polish, but code samples are pretty much self-explanatory).