# How to access data context when user leave the user control

Tags: wpf

I need to write functionality such that if the user leaves the `UserControl` (i.e. navigates away from the control), I need to save the data which resides in the view model of the user control.

I've tried connecting a handler to the `Unloaded` event of the user control, but I'm unable to access the `DataContext`.

Is there a way by which I can capture the event so I can save the data of the view model associated with the user control.

Answer (score 2):

Use the LostFocus event instead of the Unloaded, because the Unloaded event won't necessarily be raised if the user navigate to another control.

From the event handler in your Code Behind file, you should have access to the DataContext.

Comment: +1, note that you can use an interaction trigger if you don't want to write any code behind: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21942689/2428407