# How to access events in child ViewModel while following MVVM format

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I am working with an app in Xamarin, but I want to make sure I am doing everything correctly as I go along. I have a `Dialpad` control that I display in `MainPage` through `<ctrl:Dialpad x:Name="dialpad" HeightRequest="600"/>`. `MainPage` has a `BindingContext` of `MainPageViewModel` and `Dialpad` has one of `DialpadViewModel`. I have an event in `DialpadViewModel` that gets called whenever a number key is pressed on the dialpad. For simplicity's sake, these buttons are meant to update a label on `MainPage`. In order to do this, I have this code in the code-behind file of `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //add an event handler for a button pressed
        InitializeEvents();

    }

    void InitializeEvents ()
    {
        //whenever the keypad is pressed
        ((DialpadViewModel)dialpad.BindingContext).OnKeyPressed += ((MainPageViewModel)BindingContext).DialpadButtonPressed;
        ((DialpadViewModel)dialpad.BindingContext).OnDial += ((MainPageViewModel)BindingContext).DialAddress;
        ((DialpadViewModel)dialpad.BindingContext).OnBackspace += ((MainPageViewModel)BindingContext).Backspace;
    }
```

I know, that according to the MVVM format, there is supposed to be NO code in the code-behind file. However, I have no idea how to approach this otherwise. Any advice?

Comment: Check out this question, and if it doesn't answer it edit your post to reflect that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048517/wpf-calling-commands-via-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not MVVM.

You basically have two options here.

1. Expose an instance of a `DialpadViewModel` from the `MainPageViewModel` class. The latter can then subscribe to events of the former without any code-behind involved.

The `Dialpad` element in the `MainPage` binds to the `DialpadViewModel` property of the `MainPageViewModel`:

```
<ctrl:Dialpad x:Name="dialpad" BindingContext="{Binding DialpadViewModel}" HeightRequest="600"/>
```

Make sure that you don't explicitly set the `BindingContext` property of `dialpad` anywhere else.

2. Use an event aggregator or a messenger to communicate between the `DialpadViewModel` and the `MainPageViewModel` in a loosely coupled way. [This](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) blog post explains the concept.

In short, there is no direct reference from one view model to another. Instead, they communicate with each other via a common object of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `EventToCommandBehavior`.

> ### Overview
>
> The `EventToCommandBehavior` class is a reusable Xamarin.Forms custom
>   behavior that executes a command in response to *any* event firing. By
>   default, the event arguments for the event will be passed to the
>   command, and can be optionally converted by an
>   [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.ivalueconverter)
>   implementation.
>
> The following behavior properties must be set to use the behavior:
>
> - **EventName** – the name of the event the behavior listens to.
> - **Command** – the `ICommand` to be executed. The behavior expects to find the `ICommand` instance on the
>     [`BindingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.bindingcontext#Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_BindingContext)
>     of the attached control, which may be inherited from a parent element.
>
> The following optional behavior properties can also be set:
>
> - **CommandParameter** – an `object` that will be passed to the command.
> - **Converter** – an [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.ivalueconverter)
>     implementation that will change the format of the event argument data
>     as it's passed between *source* and *target* by the binding engine.
>
> Note: The `EventToCommandBehavior` is a custom class that can be located  in the [EventToCommand Behavior
>   sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/behaviors-eventtocommandbehavior),
>   and is not part of Xamarin.Forms.
>
> ### Creating the Behavior
>
> The `EventToCommandBehavior` class derives from the `BehaviorBase<T>`
>   class, which in turn derives from the
>   [`Behavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.behavior-1)
>   class. The purpose of the `BehaviorBase<T>` class is to provide a base
>   class for any Xamarin.Forms behaviors that require the
>   [`BindingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.bindingcontext#Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_BindingContext)
>   of the behavior to be set to the attached control. This ensures that
>   the behavior can bind to and execute the `ICommand` specified by the
>   `Command` property when the behavior is consumed.
>
> The `BehaviorBase<T>` class provides an overridable
>   [`OnAttachedTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.behavior-1.onattachedto#Xamarin_Forms_Behavior_1_OnAttachedTo_Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_)
>   method that sets the
>   [`BindingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.bindingcontext#Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_BindingContext)
>   of the behavior and an overridable
>   [`OnDetachingFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.behavior-1.ondetachingfrom#Xamarin_Forms_Behavior_1_OnDetachingFrom_Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_)
>   method that cleans up the `BindingContext`. In addition, the class
>   stores a reference to the attached control in the `AssociatedObject`
>   property.
>
> #### Implementing Bindable Properties
>
> The `EventToCommandBehavior` class defines four
>   [`BindableProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableproperty)
>   instances that execute a user defined command when an event fires.
>   These properties are shown in the following code example:
>
> C#:
>
> ```cs
> public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<View> {  
>     public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty =
>       BindableProperty.Create ("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null, propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);
>     public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
>       BindableProperty.Create ("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);
>     public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
>       BindableProperty.Create ("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);
>     public static readonly BindableProperty InputConverterProperty =
>       BindableProperty.Create ("Converter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);
>
>     public string EventName { ... }
>     public ICommand Command { ... }  
>     public object CommandParameter { ... }
>     public IValueConverter Converter { ...  }  
>     ...  
> }
> ```
>
> When the `EventToCommandBehavior` class is consumed, the `Command`
>   property should be data bound to an `ICommand` to be executed in
>   response to the event firing that's defined in the `EventName`
>   property. The behavior will expect to find the `ICommand` on the
>   [`BindingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.bindingcontext#Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_BindingContext)
>   of the attached control.
>
> By default, the event arguments for the event will be passed to the
>   command. This data can be optionally converted as it's passed between
>   *source* and *target* by the binding engine, by specifying an [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.ivalueconverter)
>   implementation as the `Converter` property value. Alternatively, a
>   parameter can be passed to the command by specifying the
>   `CommandParameter` property value.
>
> #### Implementing the Overrides
>
> The `EventToCommandBehavior` class overrides the
>   [`OnAttachedTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.behavior-1.onattachedto#Xamarin_Forms_Behavior_1_OnAttachedTo_Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_)
>   and
>   [`OnDetachingFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.behavior-1.ondetachingfrom#Xamarin_Forms_Behavior_1_OnDetachingFrom_Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_)
>   methods of the `BehaviorBase<T>` class, as shown in the following code
>   example:
>
> C#:
>
> ```cs
> public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<View> {
>   ...  
>   protected override void OnAttachedTo (View bindable) {
>     base.OnAttachedTo (bindable);
>     RegisterEvent (EventName);
>   }
>
>   protected override void OnDetachingFrom (View bindable) {
>     DeregisterEvent (EventName);
>     base.OnDetachingFrom (bindable);
>   }
> ... 
> }
> ```
>
> The
>   [`OnAttachedTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.behavior-1.onattachedto#Xamarin_Forms_Behavior_1_OnAttachedTo_Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_)
>   method performs setup by calling the `RegisterEvent` method, passing
>   in the value of the `EventName` property as a parameter. The
>   [`OnDetachingFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.behavior-1.ondetachingfrom#Xamarin_Forms_Behavior_1_OnDetachingFrom_Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_)
>   method performs cleanup by calling the `DeregisterEvent` method,
>   passing in the value of the `EventName` property as a parameter.
>
> #### Implementing the Behavior Functionality
>
> The purpose of the behavior is to execute the command defined by the
>   `Command` property in response to the event firing that's defined by
>   the `EventName` property.    }The core behavior functionality is shown in
>   the following code example:
>
> C#:
>
> ```cs
> public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<View> {
> ...  
> void RegisterEvent (string name) {
>     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (name)) {
>       return;
>     }
>
>     EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType ().GetRuntimeEvent (name);
>     if (eventInfo == null) {
>       throw new ArgumentException (string.Format ("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
>     }
>     MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(EventToCommandBehavior).GetTypeInfo ().GetDeclaredMethod ("OnEvent");
>     eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate (eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this);
>     eventInfo.AddEventHandler (AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
>   }
>
>   void OnEvent (object sender, object eventArgs) {
>     if (Command == null) {
>       return;
>     }
>
>     object resolvedParameter;
>     if (CommandParameter != null) {
>       resolvedParameter = CommandParameter;
>     } else if (Converter != null) {
>       resolvedParameter = Converter.Convert (eventArgs, typeof(object), null, null);
>     } else {
>       resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
>     }        
>
>     if (Command.CanExecute (resolvedParameter)) {
>       Command.Execute (resolvedParameter);
>     }
>   }
> ...
> }
> ```
>
> The `RegisterEvent` method is executed in response to the
>   `EventToCommandBehavior` being attached to a control, and it receives
>   the value of the `EventName` property as a parameter. The method then
>   attempts to locate the event defined in the `EventName` property, on
>   the attached control. Provided that the event can be located, the
>   `OnEvent` method is registered to be the handler method for the event.
>
> The `OnEvent` method is executed in response to the event firing
>   that's defined in the `EventName` property. Provided that the
>   `Command` property references a valid `ICommand`, the method attempts
>   to retrieve a parameter to pass to the `ICommand` as follows:
>
> - If the `CommandParameter` property defines a parameter, it is retrieved.
> - Otherwise, if the `Converter` property defines an [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.ivalueconverter)
>     implementation, the converter is executed and converts the event
>     argument data as it's passed between *source* and *target* by the
>     binding engine.
> - Otherwise, the event arguments are assumed to be the parameter.
>
> The data bound `ICommand` is then executed, passing in the parameter
>   to the command, provided that the
>   [`CanExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.command.canexecute#Xamarin_Forms_Command_CanExecute_System_Object_)
>   method returns `true`.
>
> Although not shown here, the `EventToCommandBehavior` also includes a
>   `DeregisterEvent` method that's executed by the
>   [`OnDetachingFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.behavior-1.ondetachingfrom#Xamarin_Forms_Behavior_1_OnDetachingFrom_Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_)
>   method. The `DeregisterEvent` method is used to locate and deregister
>   the event defined in the `EventName` property, to cleanup any
>   potential memory leaks.
>
> ### Consuming the Behavior
>
> The `EventToCommandBehavior` class can be attached to the
>   [`Behaviors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.behaviors#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_Behaviors)
>   collection of a control, as demonstrated in the following XAML code
>   example:
>
> XAML:
>
> ```xml
> <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
>     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
>         <DataTemplate>
>             <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
>         </DataTemplate>
>     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
>     <ListView.Behaviors>
>         <local:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemSelected" Command="Binding OutputAgeCommand}" Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}" />
>     </ListView.Behaviors>
> </ListView>
> <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItemText}" />
> ```
>
> The equivalent C# code is shown in the following code example:
>
> C#:
>
> ```cs
> var listView = new ListView();
> listView.SetBinding(ItemsView<Cell>.ItemsSourceProperty, "People");
> listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
> {
>     var textCell = new TextCell();
>     textCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Name");
>     return textCell;
> });
> listView.Behaviors.Add(new EventToCommandBehavior {
>     EventName = "ItemSelected",
>     Command = ((HomePageViewModel)BindingContext).OutputAgeCommand,
>     Converter = new SelectedItemEventArgsToSelectedItemConverter()
> });
>
> var selectedItemLabel = new Label();
> selectedItemLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "SelectedItemText");
> ```
>
> The `Command` property of the behavior is data bound to the
>   `OutputAgeCommand` property of the associated ViewModel, while the
>   `Converter` property is set to the `SelectedItemConverter` instance,
>   which returns the
>   [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.selecteditem#Xamarin_Forms_ListView_SelectedItem)
>   of the
>   [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview)
>   from the
>   [`SelectedItemChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selecteditemchangedeventargs).
>
> At runtime, the behavior will respond to interaction with the control.
>   When an item is selected in the
>   [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview),
>   the
>   [`ItemSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.itemselected)
>   event will fire, which will execute the `OutputAgeCommand` in the
>   ViewModel. In turn this updates the ViewModel `SelectedItemText`
>   property that the
>   [`Label`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label)
>   binds to, as shown in the following screenshots:
>
> [image: Sample application with EventToCommandBehavior]
>
> The advantage of using this behavior to execute a command when an
>   event fires, is that commands can be associated with controls that
>   weren't designed to interact with commands. In addition, this removes
>   boilerplate event handling code from code-behind files.

<sub>**Source:** [Reusable EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior)</sub>